# Is there a way to simplify this expression with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Is there a way to simplify the expression
$$ \frac{a+bz+z^2}{a-bz+z^2}
 $$
without having to calculate everything by setting $z=x+iy$ and then making the denominator real by multiplying with the complex conjugate? In particular: is there a way to tell if the expression above lies inside the complex unit ball immediately?

**EDIT:**
Now suppose further that the roots of the bottom polynomial $z_1,z_2$ have a positive real part. Is this expression in the complex unit ball if we limit $z$ to the complex numbers with negative real part? Specifically I'm interested in the case $a=12, b=6$.

Comment: you may use partial fractions ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z_1,z_2$ be the roots of of the bottom polynomial. Then the expression factors to

$$\frac{z+z_1}{z-z_1}\cdot\frac{z+z_2}{z-z_2}$$

which in general is unbounded as $z$ approaches either root.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: @mathemagician99 You can use the max principle on the boundary $\operatorname{Re}(z) = 0$ since all holomorphic functions obey the max principle.